# Domino Server 8.5 Configuration

Tags: lotus-domino

I am installing Domino server 8.5 on a virtual machine, while configuring i could only see TCP/IP Network port is detected, the setup cannot detect NETBIOS port. Is there a way to add this port?

Regards,
Haseena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up the server, start the Domino Administrator client, connect to the server, go to the Configuration tab, make sure that the Tools section on the right side of the screen is expanded, select Server, and click Setup Ports.  That should allow you to enable a NetBIOS port.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, I would stick with the TCP/IP protocol and keep the NetBios port disabled unless there is a very specific need for it.

[Tuning IBM System x Servers for Performance](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/sg245287.html?OpenDocument&S_TACT=104AHW29&S_CMP=DVCHL):

> Although most applications still support other protocols in addition
>   to TCP/IP, support for these protocols is gradually phasing out and
>   features are often only supported with TCP/IP. For example, both Lotus
>   Domino clustering and Microsoft clustering require TCP/IP to function
>   properly.